# Error running DisplayMessageActivity: The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm a total noob to Android and trying to learn using the tutorial page. This is my 3rd attempt on separate occasions and I keep getting to this point and getting errors :( Everything in the tutorial went fine until I added the DisplayMessageActivity part. Now I get the error:

Error running DisplayMessageActivity: The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter
I've looked over the other posts in here with similar problems, but none of these seems to work and I'm stuck :(

Any help is appreciated :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ddani.myfirstapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My DisplayMessageActivity file

```
package com.example.ddani.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(message);
}
```